# Flutter WooCommerce Customer registeration failed using Dio and jwt?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce-rest-api

I am buidling flutter woocommerce store app for customers. I want to create/register a new customer using Dio() and I am using WordPress Plugin JWT Authentication for WP REST API for authentication. Here if i want to access URL for Customers Its showing following response. URL= "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers"

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

CUSTOMER MODEL FILE IS...

```
class CustomerModel {
  String email;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String password;
  CustomerModel(
      {required this.email,
      required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.password});
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
    map.addAll({
      'email': email,
      'first_name': firstName,
      'last_name': lastName,
      'password': password,
      'username': email
    });
    return map;
  }
}
```

API MODEL FILE IS...

```
Future<bool> createCustomer(CustomerModel model) async {
    var authToken =
        base64.encode(utf8.encode(Config.key + ':' + Config.sceret));
    print(authToken);
    bool ret = false;
    try {
      print("${Config.url+ Config.customerURL}");
      var response = await Dio().post(Config.url + Config.customerURL,
          data: model.toJson(),
          options: new Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $authToken',
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
          }));

      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        ret = true;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 404) {
        ret = false;
      } else {
        ret = false;
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`404` means that `url` that you are requesting is not exist on the server.
Double-check the actual URL you are requesting and compare with expected one.

> 404 Not Found
> The requested resource could not be found but may be available in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.